# TopicClient send hanging when using azure webjob SDK

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-webjobssdk

I have a webjob that is using the Webjob extension sdk, and a function that is manually triggered and is reading/writing to service bus.

When sending a message it seems to hang.

here is the relevant code:

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration
            {
                StorageConnectionString = decryptedStorageConnectionString,
                DashboardConnectionString = decryptedDashboardConnectionString,
            };
            config.UseTimers();
            var host = new JobHost(config);

            host.CallAsync(typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(myJob)));

            // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
            host.RunAndBlock();

[NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public void myJob(TextWriter log)
        {
...
 this.Client = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connection, ConstantStrings.IncidentResponseTopicName);
this.Client.Send(args);

}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
The request operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:09.7322175. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101 TrackingId:fdbd3e20-c1b7-4829-8ebd-b9b14962c13f, Timestamp:1/9/2017 10:14:07 AM

System.TimeoutException: The request operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:09.9496489. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101 TrackingId:570d2e9f-cd9f-4bb5-8d52-45ecf026df3f, Timestamp:1/9/2017 10:15:18 AM
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] Server stack trace: 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] Exception rethrown at [0]: 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] Exception rethrown at [1]: 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c__DisplayClass8_1.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] Exception rethrown at [2]: 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__9_3(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] Exception rethrown at [3]: 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpTransactionalAsyncResult`1.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__18_3(TIteratorAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult a)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] Exception rethrown at [4]: 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndUpdateCommand(IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnEndComplete(IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO] Exception rethrown at [5]: 
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.OnComplete(TrackingContext trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 lockTokens, TimeSpan timeout)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.Complete(TrackingContext trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 lockTokens, TimeSpan timeout)
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ReceiveContext.Complete()
[01/09/2017 10:15:18 > ff1c90: INFO]    at MyJob.myJob.<ExecuteJob>b__4_0(BrokeredMessage request)
```

Everything worked well when I used a regular Azure webjob. When I moved the code to Azure Webjob SDK this hanging started. 
Another interesting thing is, that when running this on my local machine everything seems to work well, this happens only when deploying the code to Azure Webjobs

Any idea???

Comment: Why are you using `host.CallAsync` ? in your example the method is not async. also are you sure about the connection string ?

Comment: Yes, evertying works well when I run it locally.

Comment: Can you try using `host.Call` ?

Comment: I tried, it does help :(

Comment: So problem solve ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant does *not* help

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I assumed that you are using [﻿Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions > TimerTrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions) to schedule your other jobs, and manually invoking the `myJob` function asynchronously to read/write messages from/to your service bus when the JobHost starts up.

> System.TimeoutException: The request operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:09.9496489. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

As mentioned in the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions#timeoutexception) about Service Bus messaging `TimeoutException`:

> A [TimeoutException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timeoutexception.aspx) indicates that a user-initiated operation is taking longer than the operation timeout.
>   You should check the value of the [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit) property, as hitting this limit can also cause a TimeoutException.
>
> The server did not respond to the requested operation within the specified time which is controlled by [OperationTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagingfactorysettings#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_MessagingFactorySettings_OperationTimeout).

I assumed that you could try to increase `OperationTimeout` and add retry logic as follows to build your `TopicClient`:

```html
var builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder("{ServicesBusConnectionString}")
{
    OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
};
var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(builder.ToString());
TopicClient topicClient = messagingFactory.CreateTopicClient("{TopicName}");
topicClient.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(
             TimeSpan.Zero,
             TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
             2);
topicClient.Send("{BrokeredMessage}");
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce but that doesn't help. Also the same code runs perfectly find locallyf and only failes when deployed to an azure webjob.
Another interesting thing is that when I invoke the function without using azure SDK extensions everything works well, even when deployed. So this feels like a bug in azure webjob